# Extract GZ file with Java

Tags: java, compression, gzip, gzipinputstream

I'm trying to extract a `CSV` file from a `GZ` file.

So far, I've tried the following ways to make this operation:

```
Archiver archiver = ArchiverFactory.createArchiver(null, CompressionType.GZIP);
archiver.extract(archiveFile, destFile);
```

Or

```
GzipCompressorInputStream archive = new GzipCompressorInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(archiveFile)));
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
IOUtils.copy(archive, out);
out.close();
archive.close();
```

Or

```
GZIPInputStream archive= new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(archiveFile));
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
IOUtils.copy(archive, out);
out.close();
archive.close();
```

I've also given a try to *Snappy* which is a (un)compression lib on github.

**In every case, I got the following error displayed**:

```
java.io.IOException: Gzip-compressed data is corrupt
```

I've checked the `GZ` files validity with the following console command, which says everything should be alright.

```
gzip -v -t MyFileToUncompress.csv.gz
MyFileToUncompress.csv.gz: OK
```

The `GZ` files were compressed by console command or by Java itself or on a Windows. Same result so far.

Is there something I'm doing wrong or is that an issue on my Java (JDK 1.7 or 1.8 produce the same exception) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code I use for gunzip, though it doesn't look as though it would produce a different outcome as it is essentially same as your third example:

```
try(final OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(fout);
    final InputStream in   = new GZIPInputStream(Files.newInputStream(fin))) {
    in.transferTo(out);
}
```

However it is worth checking whether your result changes using latest JDK, and also check that `gzip -d MyFileToUncompress.csv.gz` generates the expected file back.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. The code produces the same issue. The `gzip` command does generate the file back which is really weird. Changing the JDK to version 12 does not change anything. I don't know what can be the cause and why the compression works but not the uncompression.